# Android Studio activity landscape

Tags: java, android, xml, apk, landscape

Im trying to create a table in Android Studio with several fields, so the common Vertical mode for the activities doesn't seem useful to me.

I just want to change only one activity landscape mode to "Horizontal" and whenever i just change from this activity to another, go back to the regular "Vertical" mode.

I have tried searching on Google but all i found is just tutorials for changing the entire app to Vertical or Horizontal and i don't need that.

How can i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this in your AndroidManifest.xml for each activity individually. For example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyHorizontalActivity"
    android:label="@string/my_horiz_activity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```